# Coding questions

Tags: query

I have a question, which i can't solve. Here are 2 tables:

Customers:

```
| Credit_Card_ind | Credit | Account ID |
|-----------------|--------|:----------:|
| 1               | 1      | תל אביב    |
| 1               | 2      | ירושלים    |
| 2               | 1      | באר שבע    |
| 2               | 3      | תל אביב    |
| 3               | 4      | ירושלים    |
| 4               | 5      | הרצליה     |
```

Credit_Cards:

```
Credit_card_ind  Credit   AccountID
0 (no card)       1000        1
1 (card)          5000        2
0                 2300        3
1                 30000       4
```

There are 5 questions, but with a catch:

1. All the customers with overall credit over 5000
2. No customers if one of their accountsID has no credit card
3. All of the accountIDs that have credit below 30000
4. No accounts where one (or more) customers is from Jerusalem
5. All the accounts that have more than 1 customer.

The catch is all of these have to be in one query, but each is a separate group.

I started like this, but honestly, have no idea how to do it:

```
Select *, CASE when b.Credit > 5000 then ‘Condition 1’
                    When Credit_card_ind = 1 then ‘Condition 2’
        When Credit < 30000 then ‘Condition 3’
        When a,CityCode is not Jerusalem then ‘Condition 4’
        When 
From customers c 
Inner join credit_cards cc on c.AccountID = cc.AccountID
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It didn't really like the RTL/LTR combination, was pretty frustrating to get it to align somewhat properly. Not your fault of course

Comment: You should also tag an RDBMS & version. See [ask]. See also [repro] for advice on helping us answer your question better, but I've taken the liberty of queuing up step 1 for you in [sql server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85765199e226b369c486efbd91f5ed83), [postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=267015f1a7b04d62c21edf565731e3cc), & [mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c348179c070e9f72963ccdc1204604bf)

Comment: The data samples and the attempted query between them make little sense. In particular, why are you joining on `c.AccountID = cc.AccountID` when there's nothing in common between the `AccountID` column in one table and that in the other, except the name? On a different note, as far as starting is concerned, I would start with getting a clear idea what the output should look like. First of all, you should have that idea for yourself, and then you need to add the desired output to your question to let the potential answerers know too.

Comment: You don't even have a column to filter by city and some columns don't match another table definition

Comment: Before attempting to get all 5 conditions in one query, try one condition at a time and see if you can get the right result or not.  Just looking at the query, I'm sure it will error out.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement to have them all in one query, while the results you are looking for are independent and unrelated, is certainly curious.

Still, what you're looking for is most likely a UNION. Unions essentially concatenate the result sets of any number of independent queries, with one caveat: the number and type of columns returned from each query must be the same.

Example:

```
SELECT c.AccountID, 'Condition 1' FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN credit_cards cc ON c.AccountID = cc.AccountID
WHERE cc.credit > 5000
UNION
SELECT c.AccountID, 'Condition 3' FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN credit_cards cc ON c.AccountID = cc.AccountID
WHERE cc.credit < 30000
```

…and so on.
I unfortunately don't quite understand many of your requirements. What's the difference between a customer and an account? What are you looking for in the "No customers if" or "No accounts where" situations? Actually the opposite, a list of accounts who match that?

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because it is the most sensible approach to getting all of the results through a single query. In particular, hard-coding the "source" condition for clarity is good (although I would add column aliases to the first `select`) and also, I full agree with the comment afterward: your requirements are very confusing. The example tables don't appear to match on any column, you mention values like 'Jerusalem' yet no example field encodes locations, etc. Eric's comment also applies: try and correctly write each query separately. Then you can use `union` to aggregate them.

Answer (score -2):

I will show you it is easy to resolve this problem using clause **filter** from **aggregate function**.

This example works in Postgresql.

```
Select 
array_agg(c.account_id) filter (where c.credit > 500) conditon_1
,array_agg(c.account_id) filter (where c.credit_card_ind = 1) condition_2
,array_agg(c.account_id) filter (where c.credit < 3000) condition_3
,array_agg(c.account_id) filter (where c.city <> 'Jerusalem') condition_4
From customers c 
Inner join credit_cards cc on c.AccountID = cc.AccountID
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: How do you know OP has window function or not?  Also format your code properly.

Comment: @Eric: nowadays window functions can be taken as given - however this answer doesn't actually use window functions. `array_agg()` is indeed Postgres specific though.

Comment: @Eric actually made a mistake, this does not use a window function, in fact, I used the ** filter ** of ** PostgreSQL ** clause. Over another database, there is an equivalent method of aggregating text or numbers. Lastly, this is one of the first posts in the community sorry for my mistakes =).